# Rotating a pair of vectors using quarternions

Tags: 3d, rotations, quaternions

The objective is to take a pair of vectors and rotate them so that they match another pair of vectors, their corresponding pair.

The paper describing this says to minimize the error function:
$ Err  = \sum ||n'-Rn||^2 $

Where n is the orientation vector.

The textbook the paper tags then says to use Quaternions to minimize this error function and get the unknown R.

The textbook breaks down the derivation as follows, after applying quaternions:

$ Err  = \sum |n'-q\times n\times \bar q|^2 $

Using q^2 = 1 we can multiply that into the above equation and compress some terms again using this rule to get down to:

$ Err  = \sum |n'\times q - q\times n|^2 $

According to the textbook: It follows from the definition of the product of the quaternion that $n'\times q - q\times n$ is a linear function of the 4 coordinates of q. Thus there is a 4x4 matrix A such that:

$|n'\times q - q\times n|^2  = q^TA^TAq $

so we need to find the min of the above right hand side.
The solution to this is the smallest eigenvalue - eigenvector pair of the matrix $A^TA$.

So my questions are:

1. What are the elements of the $A^T A$ matrix
2. How do I get my rotation matrix after solving for this pair
3. All I have is the orientations of the vectors, is this enough to calculate this unknown R.

Any help is appreciated here, I am very new to Quaternions. Hopefully my professor responds to my email soon but if not, thanks for the help.

The "textbook" I keep mentioning is "O. Faugeras. Three–Dimensional Computer Vision. The MIT
Press, 1996."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for quaternion $q$ minimizing the following error function for some pure quaternions $n$ and $n'$.

$\sum_i \|n'_i q - q n_i \|^2$

S.t. $q q^* =1$

The product $q n_i$ can be expressed in linear algebra as a matrix multiplication of a $4 \times 4$ matrix $X_i$ representing the quaternion $n_i$ and a $4 \times 1$ column vector $Q$ representing quafernion $q$.

The product $n'_i q$ can be expressed in linear algebra as a matrix multiplication of a $4 \times 4$ matrix $Y_i$ representing the quaternion $n'_i$ and a $4 \times 1$ column vector $Q$ representing quafernion $q$.

So we have now:

$\sum_i \| Y_i Q - X_i Q\|^2$

S.t. $Q^T Q = 1$

Which is a pretty standard matrix equation. Factorizing the $Q$ we get:

$\sum_i \| (Y_i - X_i) Q\|^2$

S.t. $Q^T Q = 1$

$$\sum_i \|  (Y_i - X_i) Q \|^2 = \sum_i ((Y_i - X_i) Q)^T (Y_i - X_i) Q$$

$$ = \sum_i Q^T (Y_i - X_i)^T (Y_i - X_i) Q$$

$$ = Q^T (\sum_i (Y_i - X_i)^T (Y_i - X_i))  Q$$

$$ = Q^T M  Q$$

Where $M$ is:

$$M = \sum_i (Y_i - X_i)^T (Y_i - X_i)$$

Finally I will define the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ matrices given the pure quaternion $n = n_x i + n_y j + n_z k$ and pure quaternion $n' = n'_x i + n'_y j + n'_z k$:

$q n = X Q= \begin{bmatrix}
0&-n_x&-n_y&-n_z\\
n_x&0&n_z&-n_y\\
n_y&-n_z&0&n_x\\
n_z&n_y&-n_x&0
\end{bmatrix} Q$

$n' q = Y Q = \begin{bmatrix}
0&-n'_x&-n'_y&-n'_z\\
n'_x&0&-n'_z&n'_y\\
n'_y&n'_z&0&-n'_x\\
n'_z&-n'_y&n'_x&0
\end{bmatrix} Q$

Note that $X$ differs from $Y$ in that the lower $3 \times 3$ submatrix is transposed. This is because the noncommutative nature of multiplication of quaternions.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably it. But do you know how the final Quaternion given via the minimum eigenvalue/vect pair is ordered. Is the scalar first or last?
So far its not giving me the right orientation for lines I know are corresponding.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Scalar first, like (w x y z). Take into account that this method aligns vectors, not lines. Lines might not pass thru the origin. Also if your vectors are not of unit lenght, then you need to add some weights to the Error function accounting for that, like in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem

Comment: I am still having issues I'm afraid. When I use this method to rotate the vector ([2,1,3]) to ([1,0,1]) (making them unit vectors ofc). I do not get the vector ([1,0,1]). Or in this case its unit equivalent ([0.7, 0, 0.7]) I get a completely different vector. 

When I use the method described here on based 10, 11. I get a much closer vector but still not the same. http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/quaternion.pdf

Comment: Ummm, just for curiosity I am going to do a numerical test and will share the code with you.

Comment: Here https://github.com/mauriciocele/fast-rotor-estimation/blob/master/src/QuaternionDirect.cpp you have a working C++ code of the approach.

Comment: My approach is very similar, except in my left and right matrices I do not multiply by q. So its just the Y and X matrices you show above. This should give the same result. You take the smallest eigenvalue/vector pair right?

Comment: Yes, the smallest.

Comment: If you could tell me what quaternion you get for ([2,1,3]) to ([1,0,1]), that would be helpful (I cant code in C++ yet). If not no problem, thank you for all your help m8

Comment: It doesn't work for a single pair of vectors, you need at least 2. For a single pair there are closed form solutions far simpler and better suited than least squares solution.

Comment: Turns out python's eigenvectors are transposed. I fixed the code and it works like it is suppose to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For a single pair of vectors there is a simple algebraic solution.

If $n$ and $n'$ are unit quaternions with real part zero, then $q=\frac{n(n+n')}{|n+n'|}$ is a quaternion such that $ q^* n q = n'$.  It that $n$ and $n'$ point in opposite directions theb the division undefined, in that case you can take any 180 degree rotation in a plane containing the vectors.

That solution is also known as half-way solution, you can find implementations here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another